# Custom class for Restarting Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am, still, working on my Guess the number game. Now I want to use another method instead of `Application.restart();`. Personally I was thinking about putting code in my Class 3 and then from there call the method in the main. Unfortunately I did not succeed in doing so.

My question is how to write the again method and then call it in the main?

My code in Class3:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public again()
        {
            Random Generator = new Random();
            globalVariableNumber.number = Generator.Next(1, 1000);

            var form1 = new Form1();
            form1.label2.Text = "Goodluck and have fun!";
            form1.BackColor = default(Color);
            form1.helpButton.Enabled = true;
            form1.buttonGuess.Enabled = true;
            form1.label4.Text = "";
            return again;
        }
    }
}
```

Note I've tried countless things for `public again ();` same goes for `return again;`. This is my latest try before I decided to give up.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of C# methods.

Comment: Tutorial about classes,methods and after that try again !

Comment: Of course I've read and followed tutorials, didn't really seem to work for me though

Comment: does this code compile for you?

Comment: it runs but it is not doing a thing

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code you presented, I'll try to break it down for you, starting from the most severe:

- The code is creating a new Form (`var form1 = new Form1();` ) but never shows it. The proper way to do it in Windows Forms is to have a line similar to the following, in your Main method:

  ```
  Application.Run(new Form1());
  ```

My recommendation is following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx) Microsoft's tutorial which auto generates that code for you, and examining the created code.

- Your strategy is to create a new form every time the user want to play again. This is not recommended; The preferred way is to reset the same form to the initial setup. Also, you do not dispose the form; calling the same method (`again()`) will result in multiple forms on the screen.
- You are accessing the Form members (such as `label4` and `label2`) from outside the form itself. Create a member method, in `Form1.cs`, which will set the values from within the form's code.
- Your `again()` method does not declare its return type. If it doesn't return anything, change its declaration to:

  ```
  public void again()
  ```
- You placed the `again()` method in a class called `ExtensionMethods`. The name `ExtensionMethods` for a C# class is usually used for declaring [static extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx), I would recommend renaming the class (if you eventually feel that you need such class at all).